# Install drivers on windows 7 system from WinPE on Installer disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers

My Grandfather's computer (Win7) recently died (believe it to be some mother board issue) but his SSD was intact and so we decided to upgrade to an intel NUC system and just pop the SSD in and hope that it would boot.

If it were my own system I would just wipe the disk and start over (restoring docs etc from backup) but I'm trying to keep his system as familiar as possible as he's just about comfortable with using it and I don't want him to have to get used to a new OS/look and feel and new programs. Plus trying to find all the installation media for the software he has will probably be difficult.

Anyway, the system did boot to the desktop quite happily, however I hadn't considered that the newest NUC's only have usb3 sockets and that windows 7 doesn't come with any usb3 drivers. Therefore none of the usb sockets are working and so neither do the keyboard or mouse.

So. I have gone to the intel website and downloaded the usb3 drivers and also found a tool that can modify a win7 installation iso so that it will support usb3 for installation/repair.

I also understand that to modify an existing windows installation I can use Dism from the repair command line of the installer. What I'm confused about is what exactly I will need to run.

I have put the relevant driver files in a folder called usb3 on the root of the installation media.

Assuming the media is mounted as `D:` and the existing windows installation is `C:`.

I've looked at several web pages from microsoft and others and this (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744355(v=ws.10).aspx) seems to be closest to what I want to do, but I'm not sure whether it is intended to add drivers to installation media or to an offline system - or even if there is a difference. Also I'm not sure what the default paths are.

Do I need to mount an image (wim file)? If so where do I find that on a standard windows 7 installation? Then I presume I should follow the instructions found at the link above?

If not would I just run something like: `Dism /Image:C:\windows /Add-Driver /Driver:D:\usb3 /Recurse`?

There's also an `Dism /online` flag but I presume this isn't what I want as it implies it would modify the running OS which in my case would be the PE environment from the installation media.

Source of other info I've read but not fully understood: https://serverfault.com/questions/260370/installing-drivers-on-a-windows-system-using-winpe-preinstallation-environment

Comment: This isn't an issue for me any longer as I ended up giving up and installing a Win 10

Answer (score -2):

On the windows 7 disk there is a file "SOURCES". Open it and you see boot.wim and install.wim. choose the one you want...probably boot.win.